# ggplot : use variable with aes(x = ..., y = ...)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, aes

I'm trying to make graph thanks to ggplot and shiny by using a csv file with data about food. The following code is working well.

```
p <- ggplot(data=Aliments, aes(x = Glucides, y = Proteines))
p <- p + geom_point()
p
```

However, the columns used to make the graph can change, the user has to decide. That's why i have to use this kind of code.

```
t <- c("Glucides", "Proteines")
p <- ggplot(data=Aliments, aes(x = t[1], y = t[2]))
p <- p + geom_point()
p
```

But t[1] is a str, and t[1] isn't recognize as the name of a column. Have you got an idea for this small problem ?

Comment: Use `aes_string` in place of `aes`.